# ImageFlow module doesn't find its library in Drupal 7

Tags: views, installation, theming

I have downloaded and installed ImageFlow module and also the library library from [here](http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Download) and placed its content in `\sites\all\libraries` . this is screenshot:

[image]

but when I'm trying to enable ImageFlow it reports this error:

**You need to install the Imageflow library. The js file should be readable at sites/*/libraries/imageflow/imageflow.js. You can find the library at http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Download. (Currently using Imageflow library Library required for Imageflow)**

`imageflow.js` is in the directory. I have tested both uppercase and and lowercase for ImageFlow directory but it doesn't work. why it doesn't find the ImageFlow directiry in /libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the dev version of the module. I was having the same problem, found this issue: https://drupal.org/node/2042787
Seems the maintainer fixed it in dev but did not in the point release.

If you find documentation on getting this to work after installation, please link!

Answer (score 0):

**"The js file should be readable at sites/*/libraries/imageflow/"**

From your screenshot it seems the library is stored in sites/*/libraries/**Imageflow**/

If it's a linux box your's running the site from, it will differentiate between **/imageflow/** and **/Imageflow/**. Try renaming the folder to use a lower case "i" in the word imageflow.

Hopefully that should fix it :)

Comment: `I have tested both uppercase and and lowercase for ImageFlow directory but it doesn't work` I already mentioned it

Comment: sorry I didn't pick that up the first time. Are your other libraries working correctly such as tinymce and jquery.cycle?

Comment: Yes they are working correctly